# How to check the health of an Azure Eventhub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, health-check

I have an application that uses [Azure Eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/) as one of the services and I need to implement a public health check endpoint to my application.
To do that, I need to assess the connection to the eventhub. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you want to access the connection to the eventhub?

Comment: yes. I need to assess it programmatically.

Comment: do you mean that: access eventhub instance via code -> then check if the connection successes or fails? and which program language are you using?

Comment: @IvanYang, correct. My application uses [kafka connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview) to communicate with the eventhub. So after the application got initialized, I should be able to check the health of my application at any given time. In that check, I need to assess the eventhub connection. The application is written in [ballerina](https://ballerina.io/).

Comment: There is a managet library for eventhub. And it supports .net / java. So if you're using ballerina, I think you can only use Event hub management api to fetch it's status(like active / disable etc.).

Comment: I think you are referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/) as the "Event hub management api". There I can't find any endpoint to check the status.
Can you please provide a URL if available?

Comment: it should be [Get Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/get-event-hub). and in the response, it has a value names `status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `ballerina`, you can use the [Get Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/get-event-hub) rest api. In its response, it has a `Status` value which can be used to check the health.

For other languages like c# or java, you can directly use the Management library for event hub.